# Decode Base64 with Jackson (or Spring)

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, base64, jackson

This is the first time that I try to handle binary data so I'm quite new to this.
I'm writing a REST service for uploading stuff, and I'm going to receive a Base64 encoded String.

I've found [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#parseBase64Binary%28java.lang.String%29) (standard Java), and I've also found an internal Spring class (bad idea).

Is there a Jackson annotation to automatically decode a property from Base64?
Should I use String or byte[] in my Object?

I'm also using Spring MVC 3, so it will be ok to have a class from the Spring framework to do this.

[please, no Apache Commons. I would like to find a solution without adding more stuff]

Comment: Yep, that was exactly the class which I was referring to, "For internal use only.". (And moreover I don't have the spring-security in the classpath). Thanks for the link btw.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `byte[]` for property, and Base64 encoding/decoding "just works". Nothing additional to do.

Additionally, Jackson can do explicit conversion by something like:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
byte[] encoded = mapper.convertValue("Some text", byte[].class);
String decoded = mapper.convertValue(encoded, String.class);
```

if you want to use Jackson for stand-alone Base64 encoding/decoding.

Comment: In the end I've used the `DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(String content);` and is working but I guess that would work too. : )

Answer (score 9):

For those using Java8, Base64 encoding/decoding is now fully supported and a third party library is no longer needed. Plus it's even simpler (reduced from three lines to two) and a little more straight forward.

```
byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedString);
String decodedString = new String(decodedBytes);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an utility class with one-line solution to base64 encoding/decoding problem in official Spring [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/Base64Utils.html).

```
byte[] bytes = Base64Utils.decodeFromString(b64String);
```