# Decode base64 encoded JSON to POJO with jackson and spring-boot

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson

I have a request coming like this

```
{
    "varA"  : "A",
    "varB" : "TCFNhbiBKb3NlMRgwFgYDVQQK"
}
```

where key `varB` is a base64 encoded JSON string. something like this:

```
{
    "nestedVarB1": "some value here",
    "nestedVarB2" : "some other value here"
}
```

I want to convert it into some POJOs like this:

```
@Data
public class MyRequest {
    private String varA;
    private B varB;
}

@Data
public class B {
    private String nestedVarB1;
    private String nestedVarB2;
}
```

I went through several solutions on stack overflow like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13414890/decode-base64-with-jackson-or-spring) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39236936/base64-decode-then-deserialize-json-to-pojo-with-moshi), but I want to convert the JSON directly into an object of type `MyRequest` maybe by writing some sort of Jackson deserializer.

How can I convert the JSON directly into `MyRequest` using Jackson and Spring Boot?

Note:

1. POJOs `MyRequest` and `B` are very big and `B` could be further nested, so doing it manually would be a big task.
2. I don't have any control over the request coming, it is coming from a third party source. So, can't change the format of the request.

Comment: your are correct that you need to write your own deserializer and register it using the jackson  annotation `@JsonDeserialize(using = foodeserilizer.class)`.

Comment: Can you suggest how should I write a custom deserializer which just decodes base64 encoded JSON and then use the default deserializer? I have found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313323/how-do-i-call-the-default-deserializer-from-a-custom-deserializer-in-jackson), but how should I ask the default deserializer to treat the decoded string as JSON for rest of the object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've done some experiments and here is a simple Jackson Deserializer which should work for you.

Deserializer implements the ContextualDeserializer interface to get access to actual bean property (for example `varB`). It's necessary for detecting correct result type, because deserializer itself can be attached to a field of any type.

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ContextualDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Base64Deserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Object> implements ContextualDeserializer {

    private Class<?> resultClass;

    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> createContextual(DeserializationContext context, BeanProperty property) throws JsonMappingException {
        this.resultClass = property.getType().getRawClass();
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String value = parser.getValueAsString();
        Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();

        try {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            byte[] decodedValue = decoder.decode(value);

            return objectMapper.readValue(decodedValue, this.resultClass);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | JsonParseException e) {
            String fieldName = parser.getParsingContext().getCurrentName();
            Class<?> wrapperClass = parser.getParsingContext().getCurrentValue().getClass();

            throw new InvalidFormatException(
                parser,
                String.format("Value for '%s' is not a base64 encoded JSON", fieldName),
                value,
                wrapperClass
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example of mapped class.

```
public class MyRequest {

    private String varA;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = Base64Deserializer.class)
    private B varB;

    public String getVarA() {
        return varA;
    }

    public void setVarA(String varA) {
        this.varA = varA;
    }

    public B getVarB() {
        return varB;
    }

    public void setVarB(B varB) {
        this.varB = varB;
    }
}
```

Comment: I noticed that the request coming is in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format so I can't use Jackson serializer here. Accepting your answer as it works fine for Application/JSON asked in the question. Can you suggest something if data is coming `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: Can you please provide an example of request? Keys "varA", "varB" are on the top level of the request, or they are wrapped?

Comment: yes `varA` and `varB` are top level. Something like this `varB={base64encoded string here}&varA="some string"`. Also, I have asked a separate question related to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44384557/custom-deserializer-for-requests-with-content-type-application-x-www-form-urlenc).

Comment: just to clarify, so top level object comes as `x-www-form-urlencoded`, with `varB` which contains base64 encoded JSON, correct?

Comment: This happens for real: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/rtdn-reference  so thanks for this answer